# Euler's criterion

Tags: number-theory

An integer $n$ is a square modulo $p$  if there exists another integer $ x$ such that n $≡$ $x^2$ (mod $p$).
Theorem 1 (Euler’s Criterion). :
$1$. If $n$ is a square modulo $p$ then $n^{p-1\over2}$ $≡$ $1$ (mod $p$).
$2$. If $n$ is not a square modulo $p$ then $n^{p-1\over2}$ $≡$ $−1$ (mod $p$).

Assume that $p$ $≡$ $3$ (mod $4$) and $n$ $≡$ $x^2$ (mod $p$). Given $n$ and $p$, find one possible value of $x$. use Euler’s Criterion

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is a square modulo $p$ and $p$ does not divide $n$, then $n^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv 1\ (\ mod\ p\ )$.

So, we have $n^{\frac{p+1}{2}}\equiv n\ (\ mod\ p\ )$

Since $\frac{p+1}{2}$ is even, $n^{\frac{p+1}{4}}$ is a solution for $x^2\equiv n\ (\ mod\ p\ )$